# Active Record Retrieve belongs_to

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord

I have the two following models associated:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :language

  def self.are_visible
    self.where(:visible => true)
  end
end

class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

Schema.rb

```
create_table "languages", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name_de"
  t.string   "name_en"
end

create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "description"
  t.integer  "language_id"
end

add_index "posts", ["language_id"], name: "index_posts_on_language_id"
```

**How can I list all languages of all visible stores without duplicates?**

I want something like this:

```
@languages = Post.are_visible.select(:language).uniq
```

But this leads to the following error

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "language" does not exist
```

Of course this column does not exist, only the column `language_id` exists on the table.

I am wondering why this is so complicated because in C# Linq I would just write:

```
Repository.Posts.Where(p => p.Visible).Select(p => p.Language).Distinct()
```

And I would get all Locations of matching posts. But somehow I think I need to change my approach fundamentally to get this in active record.

**Update**: Got it working the following way:

```
@languages = Post.joins(:language).are_visible.uniq.pluck(:name_de)
```

Comment: Please, modify the text of question because it is not obvious.

Comment: @MateuszCzerwiński Updated question to be more specific.

Comment: Better approach is using scopes rather than class methods.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it set up, you have only one language per post record. You don't have them related in a way you can do this with ActiveRecord; however, you can get posts by language.

`@posts = @language.posts`

This might make more sense to have a [has and belongs to many relationship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) between these models.

Comment: In the end I want to have the languages returned, not the posts.

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggest changing the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `scope`? Then you should be able to use `select` or get languages of visible posts:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :language
  scope -> :are_visible { where(visible: true) }
end
```

of course if you have a column visible in Post table which takes only boolean values.

Edit:

Try add `join`:

```
@languages = Post.joins(:language).are_visible.select(:language).uniq
```

Comment: I have added `are_visible` to the Post class. But this does not help for resolving the language of the post.

Comment: Yes because it returns only posts which are visible then you receive a collection of posts and it is possible to filter it by language. For instance, you can call a `#first` on it and get a language of post.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT language FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "languages" ON "languages"."id" = "posts"."language_id" WHERE "posts"."visible" = 't'

Comment: Your proposal will still result in error "PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "language" does not exist"

Comment: Added schema to question

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I did not get this to work so I changed my approach a bit.

```
@languages = Post.joins(:language).are_visible.uniq.pluck(:name_de)
```